# wxWidgets v2.9.4 dialog window needs more space when using aero theme

Tags: wxwidgets

When I design a wxWidgets dialog window using the windows classic theme, everything looks OK.

But when I run the app on a machine using the aero theme, spaces become enlarged and items begin to vanish below the bottom of the window.

This is wxWidgets v2.9.4.  The problem does not occur under wxWidgets v2.8.12

Here is a screenshot of the same dialog, aero on the left classic on the right.  Notice how the OK button has vanished when using aero!

[image]

How can I solve this problem?  I would like the spacing of dialog elements to be identical under all themes.

Calling GetSizer()->Fit() hides this problem, by resizing the entire window according to the space needed by the theme that happens to be used.  However, I would like to understand this problem better.  I specify the borders around the widgets in pixels ( 5, 10, whatever ) and the font size does not appear to change ( I think ) so how can one theme use more space than another?  Something weird is going on!

Here is the code for a simple dialog that demonstrates the problem.

```
class cMyDialog : public wxDialog
{
public:
    cMyDialog()
        : wxDialog(NULL,-1,L"Test Dialog")
    {
        wxStaticText * text = new wxStaticText(this,-1,
            L"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\n"
            L"consectetur adipiscing elit.\n"
            L"Nulla porta aliquam urna,\n"
            L"in aliquam massa mattis at.\n"
            L"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\n"
            L"consectetur adipiscing elit.\n"
            L"Nunc ullamcorper euismod lacus vel condimentum.\n"
            L"Sed id magna ac nisl placerat tristique eu sit amet lorem.\n"
            );
        wxButton * button = new wxButton(this,-1,"OK");
        wxSizer * szr = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
        szr->Add( text, 0, wxALL, 20 );
        szr->Add( button, 0, wxALL, 20 );
        SetSizer( szr );

    }
};
```

This was designed using the  windows classic them and linked with wxwidgets v2.9.3.  It looks like this when run under the same theme:

[image]

However, if you stop the app, change the theme to aero, the run the app again it looks like this:

[image]

Notice how the OK button has almost vanished from the bottom of the dialog.

( Also note that you must stop the app, change the theme, and restart the app.  Sinmply changing the theme while the app is running does not cause any problem. )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The default font size under wxWidgets v2.9.4 is 9 points when the theme is 'aero', but it is 8 points when the theme is 'windows classic'. In v2.8.12 the default font is 8 points, no matter what theme was used.

The result is that if I design my dialog layouts under one theme but the user runs the app using a different theme, the dialogs are laid out differently.  The widgets need more or less space, depending on the theme.  The worst problem is that the OK/CANCEL buttons which I conventionally place at the bottom of the dialog will appear or disappear depending on which theme is selected.  This upsets users!

*Explicitly setting the font size to 8 points fixes the problem.*

( How this be!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  I cannot imagine the justification for making such a change, breaking every dialog that is upgraded. )

Apparently it is microsoft's fault - they changed the default font size 'to improve readability'. (  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero#Font )  Idiots!  Now I have to specify the font size in every application, so that the dialog's have the same layout no matter what theme the end user's select.  Sigh!

If it wasn't such a disaster, it might be funny.  wxWidgets is supposed to be cross-platform, but now it isn't even cross-theme any more.

Comment: If you properly create the dialog and insert all child controls into sizer, then call Fit() method of dialog's sizer, everything should be placed to its proper place and will take needed amount of screen size. Layout will not depend on font size, that should not be a problem. You could try to use DialogBlocks for UI (at least to learn how it should be created, it generates quite good source code). Free version of DilaogBlocks allows you to put up to 30 items on dialog window.

Comment: Of course layout depends on font size!  If the characters are larger, then the widgets must be larger to accommodate them.

Comment: You should never rely on font size in pixels, it can -- and does -- change between platforms and even different versions of the same platform. In this particular case it changed because 2.8 was simply wrong, see http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/11658

Comment: @VZ Thanks for the link.  IMHO wxwidgets should override the AERO default font size so we do not have to do it in every application.

Comment: You do *not* need to override it. Just use the standard font size, that's the whole point.

Comment: @VZ If I use the default standard size then when the user has, say, windows classic theme then the font used is 8 points.  When the user has aero, the font size is 9 points.  This makes a mess of the layout of the widgets on a dialog - they need more room when using the aero theme and so, among other things, the dialog window needs to be larger - otherwise widgets near the bottom are not visible.  It is a disaster!  To ensure that my app works under all themes, I have to enforce a constant font size for all windows, something I did not need to do under wxwidgets v2.8.12

Comment: We cannot rely on the OS's "default" size being constant. The user can set a new default size on the control panel. I, for one, never use the OS's default text size! However, I never had resizing problems on my wx dialogs (on XP or Win7)...

Comment: @Rui Curado  You make a reasonable point.  However, in my experience so few people muck around with the default font size that I have never before encountered that problem.  People do, however, often use different themes and, until I upgraded to wxWidgets 2.9.4, I never had to worry about them doing so.

Comment: The dialog layout simply shouldn't depend on the font size in pixels. The argument that "I do it wrongly but it works for 99% of people" is strange because you can do it correctly without any extra effort (likely, with less of it) and it would work correctly for 100% of them.

Comment: @VZ But of course the layout depends on the font size.  A bigger font requires bigger controls which require a bigger window.  If you do not believe this, please try the simple test code I have posted in the original question.

Comment: The dependency of the layout on the font size is taken care of by the sizers and the controls GetBestSize() implementation which takes the font size into account. All you need to do is to call SetSizerAndFit() to size the top level window accordingly. If you just hard code the size of the top level window in pixels, it can't work. If you don't, it does.

Comment: It is not acceptable to any of my clients that the size of top level window varies.  The size of every top level of every application is carefully specified.  Allowing the window size to adjust might hide the problem for a few days, until it was noticed. Such details may seem insignificant to you, but out here in the real world, clients will not pay for such sloppy work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `GetSizer()->Fit()` when you finish adding controls to layout ([see docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.4/classwx_sizer.html#abad9cedc0cbe9ade2c799da23462d17e)).

Comment: This looks like it might hide the problem.  Might be the best that can be done.

Comment: Yes, this disguises the problem, making the window larger if someone is using a theme which needs more space. +1 for now, will accept later if no-one comes up with a more elegant solution.